# Ubuntu Cloud image 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) only has one network interface (eth0)

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, cloud, cloud-computing

I'm really new in the cloud world so I need some help because after several day surfing the internet I didn't find anything.

I launch a VM with kvm using this [image](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/server/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img).

After I passed the password with the `cloud-utils` file I can login into the new VM but it only has one network interface, anyone know of any other image with two interfaces I can use? Because I need to have 2 interfaces for my project.

On the internet I found maybe in this path `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rule` I can find my local network rules to name your network cards, but in my case I checked the path and I don't have the file "70-persistent-net.rules"

Some ideas what can I do? What image can I use? Or maybe there is another way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

This does not depend on the image. You'll have exactly as many interfaces as your VM software provides.

For example, with raw `qemu-kvm`, you can add more using the `-net nic` option (and corresponding `-net tap`, `-net bridge`, or whatever else, to actually *connect* each NIC to something).

`70-persistent-net.rules` is only for assigning custom names. It does not do anything unless you already have the actual interfaces.